# Задача «Ход ладьи»

Tags: python

Сегодня утром наткнулся на [интерактивный учебник](http://pythontutor.ru/lessons/ifelse/problems/rook_move/) языка Python.

Изучил теорию и начал решать задачки, все шло как по маслу... Не отрываясь, на одном дыхании я прорешал 14 задач, а на 15 вошел в ступор... Итак, задача «Ход ладьи».

**Условие:**

Шахматная ладья ходит по горизонтали или вертикали. Даны две различные клетки шахматной доски, определите, может ли ладья попасть с первой клетки на вторую одним ходом. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки. Программа должна вывести "YES", если из первой клетки ходом ладьи можно попасть во вторую или "NO" в противном случае.

В этой задаче есть небольшой ряд условий: необходимо считывать входные данные только через input() и выводить ответ через print()

Входные данные возьмем например: 4, 4, 5, 5. #это то, что мы введем с клавиатуры.

**Моя проблема** в том, что я не могу понять и представить метод реализации решения этой задачки... Сначала я начал думать как мне создать объект "Ладью", которая будет перемещаться по массиву координат, позже мне в голову начали приходить еще более нереальные мысли... С такими задачами я еще не сталкивался, учитывая то, что питоном я увлекся всего пару дней назад! А С# я знаю только на уровне ввод/вывод информации (ну вы поняли)...

Comment: `return a==c || b == d  ? 'YES' : 'NO';`

Comment: Рекомендую для закрепления решить эту же задачу для других фигур: слона, ферзя, коня.

Comment: @vp_arth уже решил, спасибо! там в том же духе :)

Comment: старайтесь более сфокусированные вопросы задавать: *"я не могу понять и представить метод реализации решения этой задачки"* учитывая, что решение буквально: `print("YES" if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2 else "NO")` где `x1,y1,x2,y2=map(int, input().split(','))` (или аналог), то не ясно что вы ожидали в ответе увидеть: 1- описание словами как ладья в шахматах ходит (горизонтально, вертикально). И соответственно решение в том, что совпадают соответствующие координаты (это не имеет отношения к Питону) 2- как ввод распознать (split, int): в таком случае условие задачи не имеет значения 3- что-то ещё?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить данную задачу, я взял клочок бумаги и нарисовал на нем шахматную доску, подписал на ней координаты клеток. В итоге я за секунду понял как решается эта задача!

**Решение:**

```
# тут ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси x первой клеточки
x1 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси y первой клеточки
y1 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси x второй клеточки
x2 = int(input())

# ввод с клавиатуры нужных координат для оси y второй клеточки
y2 = int(input())

# когда ладья ходит, координата по одной из осей не меняется
# (если не понятно, нарисуйте шахматную доску и подпишите координаты клеточек)
if x1 == x2 or y1 == y2:
    print('YES') 
else:
    print('NO')
```

Готово! До безобразия простая задачка!

В нашем примере входных данных (4, 4, 5, 5) ладья походить из одной клеточки в другую НЕ сможет, в этом вы сможете убедиться на бумажке с рисунком шахматной доски...

Comment: Если ввести 4,4,4,4 - программа доблестно сообщит, что, мол, "YES"...  хотя по уму должна ругнуться на некорректные данные. Как и в случае, если ввести 3,5,7,9. Если, конечно, программа хорошая.

Comment: @Akina первый случай невозможен по условию (две **различные** клетки), второй тоже по условию же (числа от 1 до 8) невозможен.

Comment: is not или != вместо or решит этот вопрос

Comment: @D-side Если бы Вы брали данные из файла - согласен. Но у Вас пользовательский ввод, а юзер - существо творческое...

Comment: @Akina добро пожаловать в мир спортивного программирования, где условие выше реальности :) Что поделать, в подобных задачах принято не обращать внимания на подобные вольности, т. к. ввод хоть и идёт из stdin, выполняет его обычно автоматика и всё-таки из файлов.

Answer (score 2):

```
x1, y1, x2, y2 = [input() for _ in range(4)]
print('YES' if (x1 == x2) is not (y1 == y2) else 'NO')
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще как-то так рассуждать.

Ладья ходит только по вертикали или горизонтали (сказано в условии).

Далее замечаем:

1. Если ладья сходит по вертикали, то у неё поменяется координата `y`,
   а если по горизонтали, то координата `x`.
2. Обе координаты за один ход изменить нельзя.

Из (1) получаем, что если у данных клеток совпадаю координаты `x` (`y`), то мы можем изменить координату `y` (`x`) передвинув ладью по вертикали (горизонтали). Ответ `YES`.

Если по `x` и по `y` координаты отличаются, то из (2) следует, что решения нет и ответ `NO`.

Вообще задача очень простая и если решать подобные задачи часто, то такие рассуждения делаются за доли секунды, а иногда (на самом деле, почти всегда) решение подсказывает интуиция.

Answer (score 0):

```
step_1 = int(input())
step_2 = int(input())
step_3 = int(input())
step_4 = int(input())
if (step_1 == step_3) or (step_2 == step_4):
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
```

Comment: Краткость сестра таланта, но небольшое разяснение к вашему коду было бы неплохо.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
d=int(input())
if a==c or a==d or b==c or b==d:
    print ('YES')
else:
    print ('NO')
```

Comment: На входных данных 4 3 3 4 ваш код даст YES, хотя между этими клетками ладья за один ход не сможет переместиться.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b, c, d = int(input()), int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
if a==c:
   print('YES')
elif a<c and b<d or a>c and b>d or a < c and b!=d or a > c and b!=d:
   print('NO')
elif a<c and b==d or a>c and b==d:
   print('YES')
```

Пошел окольными путями))) но в итоге решил. Я вот уже как 5-6 дней пытаюсь учиться и получаются вот такие огромные коды:(